# ADODB RecordSet sorting date field incorrectly

Tags: sorting, vbscript, adodb, recordset

I have an `ADODB.RecordSet` which is populated by calling `ADODB.RecordSet.Open` passing through the name of a `stored procedure` and `connection`

```
Dim results As New ADODB.RecordSet
results.Open usp_GetSomeDate, connection //... omitted
```

The stored procedure returns a date called `SomeDate` as a `DateTime` and does populate the recordset correctly and successfully.

```
ALTER Procedure usp_GetSomeDate
AS    
select SomeDate from foo
```

The code then takes this populated RecordSet and calls `Sort` e.g.

```
results.Sort = "SomeDate"
```

**The problem is** this sort then appears to sort `SomeDate` by `Day` rather than the whole `DateTime`! for example, if I had the following:

```
04/07/2018 12:43:23
01/03/2017 06:32:12
08/04/2018 09:23:23
```

and sorted the results in ascending order, I will end up with:

```
01/03/2017 06:32:12
04/07/2018 12:43:23
08/04/2018 09:23:23
```

whereas my expected and desired result would have been:

```
01/03/2017 06:32:12
08/04/2018 09:23:23
04/07/2018 12:43:23
```

I can't see why the code would be sorting these as anything other than a DateTime as I am ensuring my value returned from the SQL stored procedure is a DateTime - this is what often causes the problem, looking around at other answers (of which there are not many)

How can I alter this to ensure the sort is as a `DateTime`?

Comment: Sorting a Recordset requires the CursorLocation property to be set to **adUseClient**. A temporary index will be created for each field specified in the Sort property if an index does not already exist. 
See if `results.CursorLocation = 3   ' adUseClient` makes any diference

Comment: This has solved it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Theo pointed out, the `CursorLocation` property on the `RecordSet` needs to be set to `adUseClient`

```
Dim results As New ADODB.RecordSet
results.CursorLocation = adUseClient
results.Open usp_GetSomeDate, connection //... omitted
```

Additionally, it is important to make sure the field selected from SQL is a `Date` or `DateTime` so that the recordset sorts on the date rather than a string!